# Como arredondar este número: 3084,08 SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Como eu posso arredondar este número: 3084,08 para: 3084,09 no sql server?

Comment: Isso é arredondar? o valor menor tem mais de duas casas decimais?

Comment: Não tem como eu arredondar o valor depois da virgula?

Comment: O valor que vem do banco é esse aqui: 3084.087522295

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o comando CAST, exemplo

```
select CAST(3084.087522295 as numeric (36,2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `ROUND` em conjunto com `CAST` do `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(3084.087522295, 2) AS NUMERIC(15, 2)) as X
```

Resultando em `3084.09`.

---

> [`ROUND`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Retorna um valor numérico, arredondado, para o comprimento ou precisão especificados.
>
> **Sintaxe**
>
> ```
> ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
> ```
>
> **Argumentos**
>
> *numeric_expression*
>
> É uma [expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) da categoria de tipo de dados numéricos exatos ou aproximados, com exceção do tipo de dados `bit`.
>
> *length*
>
> É a precisão para a qual numeric_expression deve ser arredondada. length deve ser uma expressão do tipo `tinyint`, `smallint` ou `int`. Quando *length* é um número positivo, *numeric_expression* é arredondado para o número de posições decimais especificado por *length*. Quando *length* é um número negativo, *numeric_expression* é arredondado à esquerda da vírgula decimal, conforme especificado por *length*.
>
> *function*
>
> É o tipo de operação a ser executada. function deve ser `tinyint`, `smallint` ou `int`. Quando *function* é omitido ou tem um valor igual a 0 (padrão), *numeric_expression* é arredondado. Quando um valor diferente de 0 é especificado, *numeric_expression* é truncado.

---

> [`CAST`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Essas funções convertem uma expressão de um tipo de dados em outro.

Comment: cast já arredonda, mas boa ;)

Comment: @LucasMiranda verdade, testei agora aqui e realmente arredonda

Answer (score 0):

Existe a função ROUND, arredonda para o número de casas decimais.

```
SELECT ROUND(23542351.4154161,2)

SELECT convert(int,(ROUND(23542351.4154161,0)))
```

Answer (score -1):

No Mysql `SELECT ROUND(3084.087522295, 2);`

Saída `3084,09`

[MySQL ROUND() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_round.asp)